# Angular Datatables - binding values in dom options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-datatables

Briefly, what I need to do is customize angular datatables adding a select statement on top, but I also need to bind a model from controller to directive.
Here's how my code looks like (took from [angular-datatables guide](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/angularDirectiveInDOM) and modifyied:

```js
angular.module('showcase.customButton', ['datatables'])
    .controller('CustomElementCtrl', CustomElementCtrl)
    .directive('datatableWrapper', datatableWrapper)
    .directive('customElement', customElement);

function CustomElementCtrl(DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource('data.json')
        // Add your custom button in the DOM
        .withDOM('lfr<"custom-element">tip');
    vm.dtColumns = [
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName').withTitle('First name'),
        DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName').withTitle('Last name').notVisible()
    ];
}

/**
 * This wrapper is only used to compile your custom element
 */
function datatableWrapper($timeout, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>',
        link: link
    };

    function link(scope, element) {
        // Using $timeout service as a "hack" to trigger the callback function once everything is rendered
        $timeout(function () {
            // Compiling so that angular knows the button has a directive
            $compile(element.find('.custom-element'))(scope);
        }, 0, false);
    }
}

/**
 * Your custom element
 */
function customElement() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
    scope: {
      model: '=',
    },
    template: '\
              <label>Column:\
                <select ng-model="model" class="form-control input-sm">\
                  <option ng-value=""></option>\
                  <option ng-value="id">ID</option>\
                  <option ng-value="code">Codice</option>\
                  <option ng-value="description">Descrizione</option>\
                  <option ng-value="time">Tempo</option>\
                </select>\
              </label>\
              '
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="CustomElementCtrl as showCase">
    <datatable-wrapper>
        <table datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" class="row-border hover">
        </table>
    </datatable-wrapper>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

DOM is exploding before loading the table.

See if this works:

```
function datatableWrapper($timeout, $compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>',
    link: link
  }
}

function link(scope, element) {
    /`enter code here`/ Using $timeout service as a "hack" to trigger the callback function once everything is rendered
    $timeout(function () {
        // Compiling so that angular knows the button has a directive
        $compile(element.find('.custom-element'))(scope);
    }, 5000, false);
}
```